# How to modify an MVC Get to return an object that works with XDocument.Load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with a 3rd-party developed Windows 8/8.1 App that relies on a Web service to retrieve data. We have the source code for the App but we don't have it for the web service, so I need to rebuild it. To complicate matters, I can't make changes to the App because it was sideloaded on a number of devices.

Even though I was able to decompile the web service's DLL, it didn't get me to a working point. The hurdle right now seems to be that XDocument.Load cannot process the returned stream.

Here's the AppCode:

```
    public async Task<CustomerModel> ReadDataFromXml(string address)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(address);

        // check that response was successful or throw exception
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var streamResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        var xDocumentObject = XDocument.Load(streamResponse);

        var contents = from contact in xDocumentObject.Descendants(Constants.CUSTOMER_TAG)
                       select new { 
                       ...
```

I'm using VS 2013 to build the service with the built in MVC ASP.NET Web Application template which implements the ApiController.

The old code, after Serializing it with UTF8Encoding returned the results via

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strMessage);
```

The new code

```
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Get(string activationcode)
    {
        return _handler.GetCustomerData(activationcode);
    }
```

I believe I need this returned through the Get call which currently returns IEnumerable.

I believe I tried returning a string for the Get call

Another thing I tried was changing the Get statement to return a string and then return the XMLserialized version of the text.

```
private string Serialize(Customer cus)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Customer));
            XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter((Stream)new MemoryStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            xmlSerializer.Serialize((XmlWriter)xmlTextWriter, (object)cus);
            return this.UTF8ByteArrayToString(((MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream).ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

But that returned "Data at the root level is invalid, Line 1, Position 1"

TLDR; Is there a way to get the GET Statement return the result so that XDocument.Load in our web app will function correctly?

Comment: Could you post what data you get from `HttpClient` maybe it's json?

Comment: Please check this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115545/consuming-xml-using-httpclient-from-webapi

Comment: This is the return as text. 

    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Customer xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><Customer_Id>64</Customer_Id><Customer_Name>Chuck Norris</Customer_Name><Activation_Code>CNORRIS</Activation_Code><Activated_Date>2016-02-10T18:00:00</Activated_Date><Expiry_Date>0001-01-01T00:00:00</Expiry_Date><IsValid>false</IsValid><IsExpired>false</IsExpired><Is_Trial>false</Is_Trial><IsChatEnabled>false</IsChatEnabled><IsMoreVideosEnabled>false</IsMoreVideosEnabled></Customer>"

Comment: Actually I should add, That's the string I'm trying to return...it's not getting to the App and I'm not even sure that's my issue.

Comment: can you call web api using you browser just by typing URL, you should see returned string. And please write what data you try to parse when you get this "Data at the root level is invalid, Line 1, Position 1" exception

Comment: The API from the browser works. It seems that the parsing isn't working because it's not retrieving the data. The problem I'm having is getting MVC's **GET** to return data so that

`await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()` and `XDocument.Load(streamResponse);`

can read it.

Comment: If I use `response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ContinueWith(t =>...` on the client side, I can see the data, but due to the sideloading issue, I can't make changes to the client. I did try looking at your link...but I haven't gotten it to work, however that may be my lack of understanding of how they are sending the data.

Comment: I must admit have no idea what may be wrong, code looks ok. last thing that you may try is to replace read stream async by `string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` and then use `XDocument.Parse` to parse document.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. If anything you verified that the it "should" work.

In the end I modified the **Get** to return HttpResponseMessage and added the following:

`return new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent(serializedCustomer, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")};`

I ran into issues where the receiving object had fields not defined in the web service, but that easy enough to remedy!.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, figured it out:

Instead of returning the object, change the Get function to return HttpReponseMessage.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string activationcode)
```

Serialize the returned data your object

```
Customer customer = _handler.GetCustomerData(activationcode).First();
string serializedCustomer = Serialize(customer);
```

and use StringContent to build your return:

```
return new HttpResponseMessage
{
    Content = new StringContent(serializedCustomer, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")
};
```

Here's the functions used to serialized the data.

```
private string Serialize(Customer cus)
{
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Customer));
        XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter((Stream)new MemoryStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
        xmlSerializer.Serialize((XmlWriter)xmlTextWriter, (object)cus);
        return this.UTF8ByteArrayToString(((MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream).ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}


private string UTF8ByteArrayToString(byte[] characters)
    { 
        return new UTF8Encoding().GetString(characters);
        //return characters.ToString(); 
    }
```